# Bind array values to dropdown in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an Edit Page there I have an drop down called Role, while inserting I sent a value (like 1 instead "Role Name") to db, while retrieving to edit page I couldn't able to initialize the selected text in drop down

below is my html code

```
<label class="adjust1-label-right">Role</label>
<select id="role" class="adjust-select-combo" ng-options="r.role_name for r in Role_Name track by r.roleid" ng-model="role">
      <option ng-repeat="rol.roleid for rol in Role_Name" value="{{rol.roleid}}">{{rol.role_name}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried this but no luck

```
$scope.role = $scope.Role_Name[0];
```

My data looks like

```
[{"Role_Id":1,"User_Id":10001}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding won't work, because you are using `ng-options` in your `select` along with `ng-repeat` in your `options`, only one of them should be used.

And use `ng-value` instead of `value`, this is how should be your HTML binding:

```
<select id="role" class="adjust-select-combo" ng-model="role">
   <option ng-selected="rol == role" 
        ng-repeat="rol in Role_Name" 
        ng-value="rol.Role_Id">{{rol.User_Id}}
   </option>
</select>
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.Role_Name = [{
    "Role_Id": 1,
    "User_Id": 10001
  }, {
    "Role_Id": 2,
    "User_Id": 10002
  }, {
    "Role_Id": 3,
    "User_Id": 10003
  }];
  $scope.role = $scope.Role_Name[1];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<html ng-app="app">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select id="role" class="adjust-select-combo" ng-model="role">
   <option ng-selected="rol == role" 
        ng-repeat="rol in Role_Name" 
        ng-value="rol.Role_Id">{{rol.User_Id}}
   </option>
</select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) And one quick question I have again if I change this select will it fetch Select Value instead of text?

Comment: @Tpk43 You are welcome, if you mean when you change the selected option will it be changed in the controller?, yes it will change in the angular controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with just using the ng-options

```
<select id="role" 
        class="adjust-select-combo" 
        ng-options="r.Role_Id as r.User_Id for r in Role_Name" 
        ng-model="role"></select>
```

To set the selected role

```
$scope.role = $scope.Role_Name[0].Role_Id;
```